# Making HTTP call with Kerberos keytab in Java

Tags: java, http, authentication, kerberos, spnego

I'm trying to make a GET request to a HTTP endpoint that's protected by Kerberos authentication. I'm able to successfully initialize a `LoginContext` using my keytab and I can see the `KerberosTicket` that is being generated and successfully assigned to my `Subject`, but for some reason my HTTP requests are still coming back with a 401 error. My suspicion is that the ticket itself isn't being attached to the HTTP request, but I'm not sure how to enable this properly.

For reference, here is the code I'm running. I'm using the Krb5LoginModule:

```
        String keyTab = "~/kerberos.keytab";
        String principal = "myself@WEBSITE.COM";
        Subject subject = null;
        try {
            LoginContext context = new LoginContext("", new Subject(), null,
                    new Configuration() {
                        @Override
                        public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
                            Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            options.put("useKeyTab", "true");
                            options.put("storeKey", "true");
                            options.put("doNotPrompt", "false");
                            options.put("useTicketCache", "true");
                            options.put("isInitiator", "true");
                            options.put("debug", "true");
                            options.put("keyTab", keyTab);
                            options.put("principal", principal);

                            return new AppConfigurationEntry[]{
                                    new AppConfigurationEntry("com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule",
                                            AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED,
                                            options)};
                        }
                    });
            context.login(); // Completes successfully. No LoginException thrown.
            subject = context.getSubject();
        }
        catch (LoginException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        String conn = Subject.doAs(subject, new PrivilegedExceptionAction<String>() {

            @Override
            public String run() {
                    URL url = new URL("http://kerberosexample.com");
                    con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

                    if (con != null) {
                        int status = con.getResponseCode(); // Returns as 401 Unauthenticated.

                        // If status is 200, process response body and return as a String.
                    }
            }
        });
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at a network trace of this request and see what's actually being sent on the wire.

Comment: To enable the debug traces in JAAS (dumped to StdOut / StdErr) use `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser‌​,logincontext -Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true` >> the output is NOT pretty, as you can expect from a crypto library...

Answer (score 0):

Pointing a correct krb5.conf. should do the work.
something like `System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.conf");`